# Implicit connection in OLEDB

Tags: oledb, implicit

Met some strange behavior.
For some databases when I use ICommand Execute in my application, OLEDB open new connection for ALTER DATABASE query.
More strange that for some databases it didn't so.
I check all parameters and permissions for logins and DB It all the same.
I am in stuck, may be somebody 've met such problem.

Comment: Sounds like connection pooling. What DB are you using? SQL/Server?

Comment: Yes. Sql server.  It can't be pooling,  because on other db it works good.

Comment: Moreover I ve just check and understand that oledb open new connection for any dml query for some databases.

Answer (score 0):

So, Yes it opened new connection because there was not closed cursor (you can check it in Profiler) , and moreover You should check for not closed Rowsets in your code (I use C++).